# Trying to get AVG from one table while joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT  students.student_name, courses.course_name, grades.grade
FROM students, student_enrollment, grades, courses
WHERE students.id=student_enrollment.student_id 
AND student_enrollment.id=grades.student_enrollmet_id 
AND student_enrollment.course_id=courses.id
```

Using MS Access I'm trying to get the student names and average grade per subject (course name). When I tried adding "SELECT AVG(students.student_name, courses.course_name, grades.grade)" it did not work.

Comment: 1) Correct join (using JOIN  syntax) 2) GROUP BY clause to define groups 3) AVG on one column. There is no substitution for own research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    s.student_name, c.course_name, avgGrades.resultGrade
FROM 
    ((SELECT 
        se.course_id, se.student_id, AVG(g.grade) AS resultGrade
    FROM
        grades g
    INNER JOIN student_enrollment se ON g.student_enrollment_id = se.id
    GROUP BY se.course_id, se.student_id) avgGrades
INNER JOIN students s ON avgGrades.student_id = s.id)
INNER JOIN courses c ON avgGrades.course_id = c.id
```

Comment: Wow that worked but I dont understand how. What is this avg and result?
Why is se.course_id, and se.student_id) in the GROUP BY (and why is it seperated from avgGrades)  
I feel utterly lost :(

Comment: @YitzChalfari In table avgGrades used group by course id and student id. So we get an average grade for each student for each course. Since in the query we group by id, we also need to get the name of the course and the name of the student, so you need 2 more joins